# Meaning of factor in probability problem.

Tags: probability

A box contains eight white golf balls and six yellow golf balls. Four golf balls are randomly drawn without replacement. What is the probability that three golf balls are white and one is yellow?

I got to the answer by choosing $3$ out of the eight and $1$ out of the six. The total possible ways that four can be drawn from $14$ is $\binom{14}{4}$.

This leads to a probability of $$\frac{\binom{8}{3}\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{14}{4}}=\frac{48}{143}$$

I tried to reason another way by first finding the probability of drawing four balls in order (or so I think I did).
This probability is $\frac{8}{14}\cdot\frac{7}{13}\cdot\frac{6}{12}\cdot\frac{6}{11}=\frac{12}{148}$

I thought that if if the four balls are drawn in a certain order, the the total orientations possible is $4!$, but I realized that I was overcounting.

For some reason, when multiplied by $4$, the correct answer is obtained. What is the particular meaning of multiplying by $4$ through this route. How was it obtained? Is it just coincidence?

Comment: Choosing which of the four slots was occupied by the yellow ball.

Comment: How does being indistinguishable not make it important for the count? I imagine that the "frequency" of repeats should come into play.

Answer (score 0):

No its not coincidence. You have to pick only 1 yellow ball. And that can be picked at any of 4 instances. So we can multiply with only 4.

If you multiply it with 4! it means you are including cases like $\frac{7}{14}\cdot\frac{8}{13}\cdot\frac{6}{12}\cdot\frac{6}{11}=\frac{12}{148}$

In factorial notation we obtain all arrangements in which each instance comes on every place. But here  you don't have case when picking from 7 white from 14.